# I use skin composer, I want to create scene in scene composer, I can't add text buttons even though I created text buttons

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I create text buttons, add every image and font, but it's still disabled when I want to add button in scene composer. I'm probably doing something wrong.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library but I note the `font` label is the only one in red. Just to confirm, you selected the font using the dialog in the last image, rather than typing the name?

Comment: @Basic I also thought that there was something wrong with the font, but you can only select it, and in this tutorial 12:20 [link](https://youtu.be/eT9JklcAcPY?si=4nmlbsi6Py81iLHD&t=740) the font is also marked in red